# how to change permissions of heap in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am currently writing a kernel module for Linux and been trying to dynamically allocate a large block of memory and changing its permissions (rwx), but it just won't work.

`do_mmap` and `init_mm` seem to be missing (recognized as undefined by the linker).
A possible solution might be accessing the kernel's vma but I couldn't find a way to access it.

Is it possible to change permissions of heap in kernel space?

Comment: Shouldn't `vmalloc_exec` accomplish what you want?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it might but when i try to compile with it the compiler says `vmalloc_exec` is undefined even with the right includes

Comment: Without code to verify what you're saying, I'm not sure how we can help.  `#include <linux/vmalloc.h>`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I already included it and the message I get is: `WARNING: "vmalloc_exec" [~/chardev.ko] undefined!`

Comment: Ahh, it appears that `vmalloc_exec` is not exported. Maybe `__vmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC)` is what you want.  What do you want executable pages for? Maybe there is a better API.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thank you very much ,it worked,I was trying to figure out how to allocate a page with rwx permissions and the flag `PAGE_SHARED_EXEC` did the job

Comment: Omer you should have rewarded @JonathonReinhart

Comment: I've added an answer so that it can be accepted, and future visitors don't have to dig through the comments to find the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vmalloc_exec` is not exported for driver use, so you cannot use it.

However, [`__vmalloc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.2;i=__vmalloc) takes a page protections argument, so it should do what you want:

```
void *__vmalloc(unsigned long size, gfp_t gfp_mask, pgprot_t prot);
```

So to allocate executable pages, try this:

```
void *p = __vmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);
```